# Cascade / Delete

Tags: oracle

I have a table which has "list of attachments" from more than one tables. when i delete the primary key in the master table, it should delete the enrollid. This is true if i have one master and one slave table. But, if i have more than one master table and want to implement cascade delete, it is throwing error message of violation of primary and foreign key. because the enrollid in attachments table won't be in both table 1 and table 2.

is there any way to implement cascade on this or should i use regular delete method in attachments when deleting enrollid in table 1 and table 2.

Table : attachments 
enrollid int  - This is foreign key
attachmentname varchar2(50)

Master Table 1: department1
enrollid int  - this is primary key
departmentname  varchar2(25)

Master table 2: department2
enrollid int  - this is primary key
departmentadd  varchar2(25)

thanks in advance for your help.

CREATE STATEMENT WITH SOME DATA TO INSERT.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
   (    
   ENROLLID NUMBER, 
     DEPARTNAME VARCHAR2(100), 
     CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ENROLLID)
   ) ;   

   INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT (ENROLLID, DEPARTNAME) VALUES (1, 'DEPART1');
   INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT (ENROLLID, DEPARTNAME) VALUES (2, 'DEPART2');

CREATE TABLE DIVISION
   (    
   ENROLLID NUMBER, 
     DIVISIONNAME VARCHAR2(100), 
     CONSTRAINT DIVISION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ENROLLID)
   );       

   INSERT INTO DIVISION (ENROLLID, DIVISIONNAME) VALUES (3, 'DIV1');
   INSERT INTO DIVISION (ENROLLID, DIVISIONNAME) VALUES (4, 'DIV2');


  CREATE TABLE ATTACHMENTS 
   (    
     ENROLLID NUMBER, 
     FILENAME VARCHAR2(500), 
     CONSTRAINT ATTACHMENTS_FK FOREIGN KEY (ENROLLID)
      REFERENCES Department(ENROLLID) ON DELETE CASCADE
      --REFERENCES DIVISION(ENROLLID) ON DELETE CASCADE
   ) 

   the above sql creates the table with foreign key constraint. but, it throws error message if include the second CASCADE statement. So, i commented the second reference. Then, i ran the below INSERT statements. The first two were inserted fine. third line threw an error message (ORA-02291  Integrity constraint violated - parent key not found).

   INSERT INTO ATTACHMENTS (ENROLLID,FILENAME) VALUES (1, 'attachment1'); 
   INSERT INTO ATTACHMENTS (ENROLLID,FILENAME) VALUES (2, 'attachment1');
   INSERT INTO ATTACHMENTS (ENROLLID,FILENAME) VALUES (3, 'attachment1');
   INSERT INTO ATTACHMENTS (ENROLLID,FILENAME) VALUES (4, 'attachment1')
```

;

Comment: It would help us to help you if you could provide a complete test case that we can run for ourselves. In other words, please provide the create table statements, along with the foreign key constraints and some sample insert statements, along with the delete statement that you're seeing the issue with.

Comment: thanks for helping me. added sql code in my post.

Comment: There are problems with your script; you need to create the parent table(s) first. Also, did you mean foreign key in your department and division tables - should they be primary keys instead? Where is the delete statement that you're experiencing the issue with? Please make sure you test your script (we don't really care what the table or column names are, as long as it demonstrates the issue!)

Comment: sorry about that. I have tested the code as you suggested. please see the error message posted.

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, but you're missing a comma after the filename column and before the constraint on the attachments table. Add the comma in and see what happens?

Comment: after adding a comma, it worked. This time got a different error message. please see my post.

Comment: So you want the enrollid to be in either of the two tables, and not necessarily in both? You can't do that - you'll need to redesign your data model such that the enrollid is in a single table

Comment: Thanks. I will go with manual delete by adding DELETE statement in the code.

Comment: It's not so much the cascade, but the fact you've got two foreign keys to two different tables from the same column. That means, in order to insert a row into that table, the enrollid needs to be present in both of the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you're after, I think you need an additional table to sit between the attachments table and the department and division tables.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
create table department
   (dept_id number, 
    departname varchar2(100), 
    constraint department_pk primary key (dept_id)
    ) ;   

   insert into department (dept_id, departname) values (1, 'DEPART1');
   insert into department (dept_id, departname) values (2, 'DEPART2');

create table division
   (div_id number, 
    divisionname varchar2(100), 
    constraint division_pk primary key (div_id)
   );       

   insert into division (div_id, divisionname) values (1, 'DIV1');
   insert into division (div_id, divisionname) values (2, 'DIV2');

create table enrollment
   (enrollid number,
    dept_id number,
    div_id number,
    constraint enrollment_pk primary key (enrollid),
    constraint enrollment_dept_fk foreign key (dept_id) references department (dept_id),
    constraint enrollment_div_fk foreign key (div_id) references division (div_id),
    constraint enrollment_chk check (div_id is not null or dept_id is not null));

--- here, I have assumed that at least one of div_id and dept_id is populated.
--- If it should be that only one of them can be populated, not both, then you'll need to change the check constraint accordingly.


insert into enrollment (enrollid, dept_id, div_id) values (1, 1, null);
insert into enrollment (enrollid, dept_id, div_id) values (2, 2, null);
insert into enrollment (enrollid, dept_id, div_id) values (3, null, 1);
insert into enrollment (enrollid, dept_id, div_id) values (4, null, 2);

create table attachments 
   (    
     enrollid number, 
     filename varchar2(500), 
     constraint attachments_fk foreign key (enrollid)
     references enrollment (enrollid) on delete cascade
   );

   insert into attachments (enrollid,filename) values (1, 'attachment1'); 
   insert into attachments (enrollid,filename) values (2, 'attachment2');
   insert into attachments (enrollid,filename) values (3, 'attachment3');
   insert into attachments (enrollid,filename) values (4, 'attachment4');

   commit;
```

Then, when you do a delete from the enrolment table, you can see the row is automatically removed from the attachments table.

```
delete from enrollment where enrollid = 4;

commit;

select * from enrollment order by enrollid;

  ENROLLID    DEPT_ID     DIV_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1           
         2          2           
         3                     1

select * from attachments order by enrollid;

  ENROLLID FILENAME
---------- -----------
         1 attachment1
         2 attachment2
         3 attachment3
```